# Suppressing the ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM warnings when building from source

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, build-from-source, serialization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When building `ros_comm` from source for an ARM architecture, I get multiple warnings about the `ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM` macro. Here's a snippet:

```
In file included from /usr/catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rosbag_storage/include/rosbag/message_instance.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rosbag_storage/include/rosbag/view.h:41,
                 from /usr/catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rosbag_storage/src/view.cpp:28:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:207:56: warning: unused parameter ‘t’ [-Wunused-parameter]
     inline static uint32_t serializedLength(const Type t) \
                                                        ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:214:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM’
     ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM(uint8_t);
     ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:207:56: warning: unused parameter ‘t’ [-Wunused-parameter]
     inline static uint32_t serializedLength(const Type t) \
                                                        ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:215:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM’
     ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM(int8_t);
     ^
```

Is there a simple way to get rid of (or just suppress) these specific warnings? For example, I'm guessing I can pass a `make` flag that suppresses *all* warnings of this type: `-Wunused-parameter`. What would that look like?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243071/suppressing-the-ros_create_simple_serializer_arm-warnings-when-building-from-source/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, generally you can disable `gcc` warnings and errors by passing a `-Wno-..` variant of the involved warning option.

In this case that would be `-Wno-unused-variable`.

Btw, this is really not ROS specific at all, but a simple `gcc` configuration problem, and well documented:

> You can request many specific warnings with options beginning with ‘`-W`’, for example `-Wimplicit` to request warnings on implicit declarations. Each of these specific warning options also has a negative form beginning ‘`-Wno-`’ to turn off warnings; for example, `-Wno-implicit`.

From [GCC Command Options - Warning Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) in the GCC manual.

---

Edit: suppressing these kinds of warnings and errors is typically not a good idea. If you must do it, try to narrow the scope of the suppression as much as possible by setting the flag on the *CMake target* using `set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES ...)` instead of globally using `add_definitions(..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-04**:
Thanks a lot! And yes, the question was mostly non-ROS-specific. It's just that I was thinking there might be a way to suppress warnings for a specific package via a combination of catkin/cmake/make arguments and flags.